# How to get services' container ids in cluster using docker compose?

Tags: docker, shell, docker-compose, jenkins-pipeline

I've started multiple container services using docker-compose with following command -

```
docker-compose up -d --scale cluster-service=3
```

This starts three container services -

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                              NAMES
87b60bd2554c        xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5000/cluster-service:1.1.1   "java -cp cluster-se…"   7 minutes ago       Up 7 minutes        0.0.0.0:9077->47100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9076->47500/tcp   testcluser_cluster-service_1
b631a656f8ae        xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5000/cluster-service:1.1.1   "java -cp cluster-se…"   7 minutes ago       Up 7 minutes        0.0.0.0:9075->47100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9074->47500/tcp   testcluser_cluster-service_2
f3aeb9541fe9        xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5000/cluster-service:1.1.1   "java -cp cluster-se…"   7 minutes ago       Up 7 minutes 0.0.0.0:9073->47100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9072->47500/tcp   testcluser_cluster-service_3
```

In Jenkins pipeline, using shell script, I want to get container ids in the cluster. How can I achieve this with shell script?

Answer (score 0):

Actually using `-q` option in `docker ps` command, it only prints container ids:

```sh
docker ps -q
```

Or to get container id of some specific name use:

```sh
docker ps -q --filter=name=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Comment: This is good approach but I might have containers for other images as well. In that case,  I need containers against specific image only.

Comment: You can use `docker ps -q --filter=name=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` to get processes for a particular image name

Answer (score 0):

Utilise awk to filter on the name and so:

```
docker ps | awk '$NF~/cluster_service/ { print $1 }'
```

Check to see if the last space separated field ($NF) matches "cluster-service" If it does, print the container ID (field 1)